# while integrating Hibernate to Spring : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.Servlet.DispatecherServlet

Tags: spring, hibernate

Hi I'm using MyEclips vesion-10
I'm trying to integrate Hibernate with Spring.. so I've added 
-Spring 3.0 Core Libraries 
-Spring 3.0 AOP Libraries
-Spring 3.0 Persistence Core Libraries
-Spring 3.0 Persistence JDBC Libraries
-Spring 3.0 Web Libraries
-Spring 3.0 J2EE Libraries
-Hibernate 3.1 Core Libraries

but when I'm trying to run then it generates error HTTP status 500

```
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@3c9217
 org.springframework.web.Servlet.DispatecherServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.Servlet.DispatecherServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1358)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:806)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Jan 27, 2016 12:48:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke

SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet servletDis

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.Servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1358)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:806)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

---please help me solve my problem--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.springframework.web.Servlet.DispatecherServlet`: it should be `org.springframework.web.Servlet.DispatcherServlet` (without the e)